# Getting undefined control sequence on anything between "$"

Tags: errors, undefined

Ive worked with Overleaf before and this is the first time ive come accross this error. Ive added as many packages as i could think of. but everytime i try to use a math symbol it throws this error. Thanks in advance!

> "Undefined control sequence.
>    \N
>
> l.21           \item 123456 $\N
>                           $ "
>   My Code

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}

    \title{MATH 220 - HW 1}
    \author{}
    \date{}

    \begin{document}

        \maketitle

        \section*{1.2}
            \begin{enumerate}
        \item 123456 $\N$
            \end{enumerate}

     \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! None of the packages you're loading defines `\N`.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The error is due to the `\N` command not being defined. what output do you expect from it?

Comment: Not even amsmath? isnt \N for the set of natural numbers part of that package? If so which should I use? ALSO: my original piece of code was $ { x \in S | x \in \N} $ wasnt sure which packages contained thoses symbols, but googling it told me that it was a predefined mathematical symbol (https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: @VishnuVenkatesh are you looking for `$\mathbb{N}$`?

Comment: Ill check that. well youre right. the link i in  an earlier comment had it as "\N" some of the others came with "\mathbb{}" im surprised at the inconsistency

Comment: the link is wrong. It is better to use the package documentation rather than some random wiki page on the internet such pages may be accurate or not, it's hard to know.

Answer (score 2):

You should *define* the command, ie `\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb}{N}`

```
   \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
    \title{MATH 220 - HW 1}
    \author{}
    \date{}

    \begin{document}

        \maketitle

        \section*{1.2}
            \begin{enumerate}
        \item 123456 $\N$
            \end{enumerate}

     \end{document}
```

which outputs

[image]